# Is using slow password hashing on the client side easier attackable than on the server side?

Tags: hash, passwords, protocol-design

[As we know](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-password-hash-should-i-use), one should use a slow password hashing algorithm instead of a fast one for storing passwords, to hinder brute force attacks when the database is compromised. The problem with this is that for every login we also need to run this slow password hashing algorithm, which for remote logins could be a considerate CPU load on the login server if many people try this at the same time.

This night, I had an idea on how to solve this (in a new protocol for **password authentication**):

- The user types in his username
- The client sends the username to the server.
- The server sends a salt (and maybe other parameters) to the client
- The user types in its password
- The client calculates a slow hash (bcrypt-like) from this password, using the salt (and maybe the security parameter, e.g. iteration count) provided by the server
- The client sends this hash value to the server
- The server calculates another cheap salted hash (SHA-2-like) of the sent hash value, and compares it with the value stored in the database.
- (Optional, to avoid remote brute-forcing and DOS: wait a small time before sending back the answer, and limit the number of parallel connections for each user/IP.)

The communication should be encrypted, of course (as the sent hash value is the effective password).

(Add the obvious way of generating and storing the passwords.)

I'm assuming this:

- The output of the first hash is not really recognizable as such, e.g. there is
  no cheap way to iterate only the possible outputs of the first hash instead of
  all strings of this size. *If I understand right*, bcrypt has this property (if
  we only look on the actual `ctext` part of the output, having length of 192 bits).

  (A comment from [ZoFreX](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/61/zofrex) seems to indicate that this is not the case.
  [Any details on this?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/142/bcrypt-can-one-efficiently-iterate-valid-hash-output-values))
- The second hash is preimage-resistant, e.g. there is no significantly better
  way of finding a preimage fitting to a given hash than brute-forcing the input space.

Then we have:

- The first (slow) hash avoids (or rather slows down) brute-force/dictionary
  attacks over the password space. (It is salted to avoid rainbow tables.)
- The second (fast) hash avoids that an attacker which gets somehow read access to the
  database can immediately use the data to login into the system: The attacker will
  need to brute-force the (in the bcrypt example 192 bit large) output space of the
  first hash to find a preimage (which then would be usable as a password).

  If we think it is needed to slow this down even more, we could use a second (low-factor)
  bcrypt here instead of a really fast hash.
- Since the slow hash is done on the client-side, the server load is not as high
  as for server-side slow hashing. (I'm assuming a quite high work factor for bcrypt.)

Here are my questions:

- **Is there already a protocol which works similar to this?** (From the comments, this seems off-topic here. Feel free to mention it anyway if you happen to know one, but concentrate on the next question.)
- **Are there any weaknesses of this protocol idea** compared to a usual server-side slow password hashing?

Comment: I'm not totally sure whether this is good here or should be better on http://security.stackexchange.com/. Comments?

Comment: I would say that your first question ("is there already such a protocol ?") is security.SE stuff, while your second question ("is there any weakness in this protocol ?") belongs to crypto.SE.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann I'd go security.stack...

Comment: Is there a reason why you salt the second cheap hash?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I don't quite remember what I thought then inventing the protocol, but I suppose it was to avoid attacking the stored password table with a rainbow table or similar. I suppose it is not really necessary here, but can't hurt, either.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Why even bother sending the client the salt -- or, for that matter, *even anything at all*?? Just put a constant public GUID on your login page and have the client calculate `slow-hash(GUID || username || password)`. After which, just a quick `SHA-2(salt || client-output)` over on the server and you're done!!

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Just remember to either *[use native clients only](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/43038/25009)* or *[wait until slow-hashing becomes natively available...](https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/issues/265)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There exists something which is one step further than your idea. Look up [SRP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2945): this is a [Password-Authenticated Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) protocol; the two parties (client and server) who run the protocol end up with a newly generated shared key (which can be used to derive encryption and integrity-check keys), with mutual authentication with regards to a shared statically known secret which can be of relatively low entropy (say, a password).

In your system, this would mean that the password is first derived into the shared secret with something slow (bcrypt), and *then* use the result as the "password" in SRP. SRP has been designed so that the server stores only what amounts to a hash of the "password", not the password itself, so obtaining a copy of the server database does not allow an attacker to log in; it only makes him able to run an offline dictionary attack on the password, at which point the initial bcrypt hits him hard.

The beauty of PAKE protocols is that they are inherently immune to offline dictionary attacks from eavesdroppers: the protocol can be run "in the clear" and this still does not give a passive or even active attacker any way to learn enough to "try" passwords at his leisure. Only an attacker who hacks into the server may get such data, and even then he does not have the password (the password-derived-value-through-bcrypt, in the setup we envision here), just a hash thereof. So there is no need to establish a SSL/TLS tunnel beforehand. Even better, it is possible to use SRP *as* the initial handshake for a SSL/TLS tunnel; this is [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5054), and [GnuTLS](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnutls/) is an opensource implementation of that. A particular appeal of TLS-with-SRP is that client-server authentication is then mutual with regards to the password, which implies that there is *no certificate whatsoever*.

A possibly troublesome issue is that the number of iterations in bcrypt must be set so that it is slow (for the attacker) but still tolerable (on whatever machine bcrypt is to be executed). If you want bcrypt to run on the client, and also accommodate a variety of clients, some of which being possibly quite anemic (e.g. a 3 years old netbook, like mine: old mono-core Atom clocked at 800 MHz; also think about smartphones), then you have to tune the bcrypt iteration count accordingly. The patience of the average user being, let's say, somewhat limited, this prevents you from setting a bcrypt iteration count as high as you would like. On the other hand, you can muster 100% of the client CPU resources for that (client might be multitasking, but the user is unitask), which probably compensates much of that effect.

**Summary:** use bcrypt on the client, then use the result as "password" in TLS-with-SRP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already thought that my idea can't be such new :-).

Comment: Could we make the work factor user-definable, so the user can decide how much work to spend (and how long to wait on his typical devices) for each login, with according security gain? (Of course, with some sensible minimum value.)

Comment: @Paũlo: it can be made user-definable, but such information will be stored on the server, so it must be transferred to the client sufficiently early in the process -- which entails transmitting the user name _first_, so there will be an extra message, which can induce latency, or a modification of the TLS-with-SRP protocol, which is (on a general basis) a bad idea. I would recommend using the "sensible minimum" for every user, and hardcode it in the client. Also, this allows running the bcrypt-thingy _before_ doing the network connection.

Comment: Wouldn't we need the extra message anyway to provide the salt to the bcrypt (assuming we don't store it in the user's device in some cache - there we could also store the work factor)? Without salt (or with hardcoded salt), the attacker can use a rainbow table and only try the the images of bcrypt here.

Comment: @Paũlo: mmh... you are right. Unless you use the user name (and server address) as salt, something which I have previously advocated against, on the basis that it does not handle password change. So yeah, you are up for an extra initial message (and response) with the user name as request, and the salt and iteration count as response.

Comment: SRP already provides for a salt, which is stored on the server. so parameters such as the bcrypt work factor could be passed along with the salt or encoded as part of the salt.

Comment: @ThomasPornin `it does not handle password change` (in your previous comment) - can't the password hash be recalculated when a username changes, asking the user to supply their password for the change? (I'd also run the username and server name through some function to make it less likely to have been 'rainbowed'. But that's a separate issue.)

Comment: @ispiro: the meaning of "it does not handle password change" is that if the user changes his password, the new password will be hashed with the same salt (user name) as the old password; thus, an attacker would get both hash values can run a dictionary attack on both for the cost of only one attack. This is exactly what salts are meant to prevent. (Note that old passwords are often, in practice, passwords still used on other systems, because users tend to reuse passwords, so breaking an old password still has value for an attacker.)

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood that. (This would only be a problem if the database is breached before and after a change, or if it stores old password hashes. Plus, the attacker would need to do this for every user. I know you know this. I'm just thinking out loud here...)

Comment: @ThomasPornin Just to clarify -- wouldn't the issue of *client salts* "not handling password changes" be irrelevant since the database would still store a *server-salted* hash of the client output anyway? (where the *server-salt* **does** change on password resets) Or, was your comment instead directed to eavesdroppers on the network protocol? (Rather than just attackers having only a database leak)

Comment: @ispiro The server or database would still use *a separate server-side salt* to hash the output from the client, *not the client's* own/simple "username + server-address" salt. And this separate server-side salt *can and does* change on password resets, and also does not even need to be transmitted or sent anywhere at all! Hence having multiple before-and-after leaks of a database would still force an attack to execute an exhaustive search on every password reset and prevent the use of any rainbow tables here.

Answer (score 6):

> The problem with this is that for every login we also need to run this slow password hashing algorithm, which for remote logins could be a considerate CPU load on the login server if many people try this at the same time.

This is a non-problem. Yes, bcrypt is 'slow' - but that's compared to things like SHA, which are very, very fast! It should be possible to find a suitable work factor for your hashing that allows logins to complete quickly but would still throw a significant spanner in the works for anyone wanting to brute force your database. Remember - the number of hash operations required for breaking in is going to be much, much larger than normal operation of your site.

As for your idea, by doing the hashing client-side you are turning that hash into a password. If an attacker compromised your database, they would only need to break past your fast SHA-2 hash to find values such that SHA-2(value) = the hash stored in the database. They could then send that value as part of the login process, and merely claim they have that hash as a result of running the slow hash algorithm on the actual password.

However, the entire point of using something like bcrypt is to mitigate an attack where the attacker possesses your database - a protection you no longer have with your proposed scheme.

To reiterate: They do not need to retrieve the user's actual password, nor do they need to go through your bcrypt hashing process, in order to break into accounts - so yes, by doing that hashing client-side you would make it a lot easier to attack.

Comment: About the slowness: If I imagine the server having some millions of users, the time for all of them to log in once is about the same as the time to brute-force an average one of them (if they have not too good passwords), regardless of work factor.

Comment: About *you are turning that hash into a password*: yes. But this effective password space is large enough (assuming a sufficient hash output length) to make brute-forcing it infeasible. (Of course, this assumes that the second hash algorithm still is *secure* (e.g. with no preimage attack significantly better than brute-forcing), even if it is fast.)

Comment: On speed: Currently, you hash passwords so fast on login that it contributes zero to load. If you increase that to even adding 1% to overall server load, you will have made it orders of magnitude slower for attackers to break into accounts at the same time. It's a clear win. Hashing passwords is such a small, easy, and relatively infrequent thing for a web application to do that I absolutely refuse to believe any website needs the full speed of SHA-1 or MD5.

Comment: On turning the hash into a password: I don't see why it would be significantly harder to brute-force a SHA-1 hash given the constraints that the input must be a valid bcrypt hash. You still have the same probabilities of a collision, the same number of expected passwords to hash to see a result - you just place some arbitrary restrictions on the format of the input.

Comment: I was assuming that there is no easy (e.g. fast) way to see if a given string of right length is a bcrypt hash of a password or not. I.e. the fastest way to enumerate all valid bcrypt hashes would be to actually hash these passwords.

Comment: On speed: Assume we have a login server (for something similar like OpenID) that does not much else than authenticating users. Shifting the expensive bcrypt-call (or maybe only a part of this - at the server side we could do another small-factor bcrypt instead of SHA-*) to the client side enables us to push the work factor (and thus the work to be done by attackers) even some more orders of magnitude up without having proportionally more load on the server.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect, generating valid bcrypt hashes is trivial. Have you actually tried this in production? Is hashing passwords on login actually slowing down your server? If it isn't then I would stop worrying about it. This smells like premature optimisation, and in this instance I don't think the speed/security trade-off is worth it. You are completely scuppering security to the point where your usage of bcrypt is 100% ineffective, massively increasing complexity, and rolling your own security rather than re-using something well studied.

Comment: Do you have a link about "generating valid bcrypt hashes"? (This is actually an important point, thanks.) (And no, I actually don't have a server with bcrypt password hashes.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/821/discussion-between-zofrex-and-palo-ebermann)

Comment: For later readers: See my next question on ["generating valid bcrypt hashes"](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/142/bcrypt-can-one-efficiently-iterate-valid-hash-output-values).

Comment: A good use case to consider for the benefits of client-side hashing is MMORPGs. Imagine a server goes down and then all players try to reconnect at the same time. Client-side hashing will be beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

Server needs to store the username received from client. Its vulnerable to DOS attack. however, on (Optional: To hinder remote brute-forcing, maybe wait a small time before sending back the answer, and limit the number of parallel connections for each user/IP.) it's possible to prevent this attack, but it's not necessary that username and passwords sent separately.

Comment: The DOS attack danger is the same with the server-side slow hash calculations, isn't it?

Comment: The separate sending of username and password is to allow user-specific salting (against rainbow tables/dictionaries to attack accounts on different servers at once).

Comment: The server-side slow hash is NOT vulnerable to DOS if (wait a small time before sending back the answer, and limit the number of parallel connections for each user/IP.) but it's vulnerable to DDOS.