# bcrypt - collision-resistance against chosen salt and work factor?

Tags: bcrypt, collision-resistance

Would it be difficult to find `(cost, salt, input, password0, password1)` such that

```
bcrypt(cost, salt, password0, input) = bcrypt(workfactor, salt, password1, input)
```

and

```
password0 != password1
```

where `cost` is not too small?

(If no, then the combination of bcrypt with PAKE described in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/122/991) would be insecure.)

Comment: I would expect that it is collision-resistant against chosen salt and work factor. A reduction to breaking Blowfish might even be possible.

Comment: In this reference on [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) the `bcrypt` function has 4 parameters. What's the definition of your 3-parameter bcrypt?

Comment: I suppose it would be using an all 0 key. $\:$ ^_^ $\;\;$

Comment: In [bcrypt's wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), the function is `bcrypt(cost, salt, key, input)`. The design is sound when the password is fed in `key`, but that contradicts the comment "using an all 0 key". All zero _input_ would make sense, but some other things would, e.g; input <- cost. I wish I knew where to look for the accepted practice.

Comment: [I may have skimmed the wikipedia entry.](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0706.html) $\:$ (At first I was confused why the key and input were named that way, and why they were even different, but know I think I get it.) $\;\;$

Comment: I'm not sure why you require collision resistance here. Shouldn't first pre-image resistance be enough?

Comment: Collision resistance would stop a fake server from trying two passwords at once. $\hspace{1 in}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the original question would have been: **Yes**, it would be impossibly difficult to exhibit `workfactor`, `salt`, `password0`, `password1` such that `bcrypt(workfactor, salt, password0) = bcrypt(workfactor, salt, password1)`; but even if that was feasible, it would <strike>not matter much, because in normal use at least one of the password is unknown to an adversary</strike> matter only in certain protocols where it could allow ruling out two passwords in one try.

As to the question as *now* worded: **No**, it would not be too difficult to exhibit `workfactor`, `salt`, `password0`, `password1`, `input` such that `bcrypt(workfactor, salt, password0, input) = bcrypt(workfactor, salt, password1, input)`; but that's only because `input` is left malleable, rather than set to `"OrpheanBeholderScryDoubt"`! In any reasonable use of `bcrypt`, `input` is built as three *distinct* 64-bit *constants* (or at least values not malleable to the degree in the question).

---

The [original reference on bcrypt](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix99/provos/provos.pdf) gives it as:

```
bcrypt(cost, salt, pwd)
    state :=­ EksBlowshSetup(cost, salt, key)
    ctext := "OrpheanBeholderScryDoubt"
    repeat (64)
        ctext := EncryptECB (state, ctext)
    return Concatenate(cost, salt, ctext)
```

with text around suggesting that the `pwd` input maps to `key` (how exactly is unspecified), and that the 24-characters `"OrpheanBeholderScryDoubt"` maps to three 64-bit blocks constituting `ctext`. Predictably, implementations have varied on the mapping from `pwd` to `key`, including in ways introducing a [serious weakness](https://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/1002-advisories/jbcrypt-entropy.txt). Perhaps the initial value of `ctext` has varied also. Further, how `Concatenate` formats the output has varied (including in an effort to encode the variations used in the rest).

If [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) is a good cipher, 64 iterations of Blowfish is also a good cipher (better by some metrics, maybe slightly worse by the cycle structure), and thus for any three *distinct* constant 64-bit plaintexts, the ciphertexts per that Blowfish<sup>64</sup> should be three values indistinguishable from random, except for being distinct. By design of Blowfish and bcrypt, finding a collision with random `salt` and `key` should be expected to require over $2^{96}$ evaluations of `EksBlowshSetup`, thus $2^{97+\mathtt{cost}}$ `ExpandKey` operations, which is beyond feasible.

---

But for whatever reason, [bcrypt's wikipedia entry as I read it now](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bcrypt&oldid=499138394) states that bcrypt *computes a hash from a given input as follows*:

```
bcrypt(cost, salt, key, input)
    state := EksBlowfishSetup(cost, salt, key)
    ctext := input
    repeat (64)
        ctext := EncryptECB(state, ctext) //encrypt using standard Blowfish in ECB mode
    return Concatenate(cost, salt, ctext)
```

Notice the fourth parameter `input` and the uncertainty on if the password is fed to `key` (the original intend) or `input`. In the following I assume this 4-arguments definition, with `password` in the question mapped to `key`.

The crux is that the current statement of the question (not the originally intended and likely usual blowfish setup) leaves the choice of `input`, including as a 64-bit value repeated three times, which makes collision search feasible:

- set `cost` to the lowest possible value;
- set `salt` to some short admissible constant;
- for `j` from $0$ to $2^{20}-1$, compute and store `state[j] := EksBlowfishSetup(cost, salt, key)` where `key` corresponds to a `password` obtained as `j` translated to an acceptable `password` as 5 hexadecimal digits and an appropriate suffix; that will require a reasonable 4[GiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) of RAM, and bearable CPU time.
- repeat for `i` increasing, starting from $0$:

  - for `j` from 0 to $2^{20}-1$:

    - set `ctext` to `i` converted to a 64-bit bitstring;
    - repeat 64 times:

      - set `ctext := EncryptECB(state[j], ctext)`; the encryption is over a single block;
    - if that `ctext` was previously obtained for the same `i` and earlier `j`, then derive `password0` from that earlier j, derive `password1` from the current `j`, and set `input` as the 192-bit bitstring formed by three times `i` converted to a 64-bit bitstring; we have found a collision!
    - else, remember `ctext` and the corresponding `j` in some easily searched table (which will require only a small fraction of the RAM used previously);
  - having had no luck with this `i`, empty the table, proceed to next `i`.

For each `i` tested, we are looking for collision among $2^{20}$ random-like 64-bit values, and that has odds about $2^{20+20-1-64}=2^{-25}$. Thus we are expected to succeed after about $2^{25}$ loops on `i`, that is $2^{45}$ loops on `i` and `j`, that is $2^{51}$ encryptions, which is considerable but feasible. Twice more memory makes a machine nearly twice as efficient, and to some degree it is possible to substitute hard disk or [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSD) for the part of the RAM used to store `state[j]`, with some minor complications. Also, this can be distributed trivially, each machine using as much memory as it has available.

---

Update: I have checked two implementations of bcrypt.

[jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/) is per the original bcrypt definition, but has two issues: because it is written in Java (which is not fully compiled at least in the most common practice, and lacks built-in idioms for unsigned 8-bit variables), speed is likely significantly worst than something native, which in the particular context means proportionally less secure; also, in [that version](http://www.mindrot.org/files/jBCrypt/jBCrypt-0.3.zip) at least, cost of 31 is accepted but degenerates to less security than the minimum cost of 4, because 1<<31 is negative in Java. Oh wait, I'm not the first to step on that, here's a [corrected version](https://github.com/josephw/jBCrypt).

In PHP, the accepted practice is delegating bcrypt password hashing to a native implementation of `crypt` (see this [`Bcrypt.php`](https://github.com/rchouinard/phpass/blob/master/library/Phpass/Hash/Adapter/Bcrypt.php) or that highly-praised [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/903600)), which is a sound way to solve the speed issue. [I was told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11184568/903600) `crypt` goes to [`crypt.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt.c) then [`crypt_blowfish.c`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/crypt_blowfish.c). I now have located `"OrpheanBeholderScryDoubt"`, and the code referencing it is per the original bcrypt definition. Speed is likely quite decent. I like the idea of checking the code at runtime with a quick Known Answer Test, which also stands a good chance of overwriting sensitive values; and some modest but likely useful attempts to reduce other sources of leakage.

Comment: This looks right, and I'll probably be accepting it. $\:$