# Integer factorization based password authentication

Tags: passwords, authentication, prime-numbers, pseudo-random-generator

After looking at [this security issue at DjangoProject](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2013/sep/15/security/), I started to think in a password-based authentication that places the burden of PBKDF2 (or whatever is the hashing function) on the client. So I came up with the following scheme:

When the user types the password, the client software (browser or whatever) hashes the password to form a seed to use in a pseudo-random generator. Then this pseudo-random generator is used to build two big primes $P_1$ and $P_2$ in a deterministic way. This two primes are the authentication token, sent encrypted through the wire (like the password is sent to websites nowdays). The server side just keeps stored in the database the product of $P_1$ and $P_2$, so — to verify the user — all the server has to do is to multiply $P_1$ and $P_2$ and see if it matches the stored product.

So, what do you think of this method? Is it secure? How big must $P_1$ and $P_2$ be  for this to work? And in the prime generation process, would be better to use some algorithm like Mersenne-Twister ( with huge period size), or Rabbit (which is cryptographically secure), or doesn't it matter?

I think the hashing pass to get the seed must use something like PBKDF2, to make it hard to brute-force attack (like it is today, but it is done on client side). The drawback I see is that rainbow tables with the most common passwords could be built for easy look-up of the stored products. But this problem is easy to circumvent, by using the user name plus the website host (or some website-specific token) to salt the password hashing.

Comment: Why not the much simpler "The client software applies a password-hashing algorithm $\hspace{1.43 in}$ to the password, obtaining the authentication token, and the server can verify that $\hspace{1.41 in}$ because it stores the SHA-256 hash of that string."$\hspace{.01 in}$? $\;$

Comment: Well, I believe that is the same reason the plain password is not stored on the server (or partially): if anyone can read the database, he/she will be able to login into the system.

Comment: Check out [the Secure Remote Password Protocol (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol). It's the "right" way to do password authentication with small shared secrets, and has the additional benefit that the user can authenticate the server in the process.

Comment: Uhh... how? $\:$ If the password-hashing algorithm was a password-based kdf, then there would be a simple reduction from such an attack to (an) attack(s) on SHA-256's onewayness and/or the password-based kdf's security. $\;\;\;$

Comment: Sorry. I understood now what you suggested... it really seems better.

Comment: @RickyDemer I'm missing something. Wouldn't that require the server keeps passwords unsalted, or that the salts are shared with the users? Ivella, that's not a good salt. User aliases are public (I assume) as is the website name. You'd probably stall the adversary a bit but an attack is still feasible.

Comment: Ivella's scheme would also require that the salts are shared with the users. $\:$

Comment: What is the problem with that salt shared with the user or public salt? I see it more as an user+site IV/nonce than a proper salt. In currently deployed schemes, if the attacker has read access to the stored passwords, it would see the salt. It is no secret, right?

Comment: Also have a look at [my similar question two years ago](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/116/58). It doesn't use prime numbers, but more or less the algorithm proposed by Ricky Dehmer. (And the accepted answer tells to combine it with SRP).