# Hash based code obfuscation?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, software-obfuscation

The code

```
if(str1 == "abc") {}
```

can be converted to

```
if(hash(str1) == 0x8732e) {} // assume hash("abc") == 0x8732e
```

to obfuscate the code.

But they are not equivalent when hash collision occurs; e.g., another string `xyz`'s hash value is the same as `abc`.

That is true theoretically. But is it an issue in real-life when the method above is used to obfuscate code? Is it a well accepted obfuscation method?

**Edit:** after a little research, I guess what I need is a one-way collision-free string transformation function, as I don't care the length of the output. Any suggestions? Any mature implementations?

Comment: [Also posted on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/133064/971).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Don't worry about collisions, if your hash value is long enough. If you use a cryptographic hash (full length), finding a collision or a second preimage is impossible for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the inputs you're hashing aren't long enough with enough entropy, the hashes can be inverted by an adversary who is willing to brute force the entire range of possible inputs.

For example, hashing `abc` provides little barrier to those who are dedicated at deobfuscated your program, as it takes almost no time to calculate hashes for all possible 3 character strings.

The adversary can build a [table of all inputs up to a certain size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) and proceed to crack your obfuscated data in negligible time. If your adversary has financial motivation, this probably will not protect your code.

You could opt for additional protection by using [slow, salted hashes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/28/29554), which are usually employed to protect passwords. Using a salt can prevent your adversary from precomputing the table before he has access to your source code. The downside is that using a slow hash in an effective manner will cause a non negligible performance hit to your application.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the table attack example Ella gave above^, you would need a hash function which is also a CSPRNG, in order to 'pad' the string. In this manner, an invertible bijection may be constructed where no two hashings are associated with the same string ie; a one way trapdoor function.

Comment: It'd be nice if you listed/linked which functions qualify as CSPRNGs. I read that one of the older SHA algo's qualifies as a CSPRNG. I tentatively assume that newer members of the SHA family will have the same properties, even though the underlying algos themselves have little in common. Specifically, does SHA3 qualify as a CSPRNG? Generally, how safe is it to assume that it's safe to drop a new-and-improved family member (SHA2,SHA3) in place of an older one (SHA1,SHA2)?